# What's the difference between "contraception" and "contraceptive"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, nouns

Definition of *contraception*:

> The deliberate use of artificial methods or other techniques to prevent pregnancy as a consequence of sexual intercourse. The major forms of artificial contraception are: barrier methods, of which the commonest is the condom or sheath; the contraceptive pill, which contains synthetic sex hormones which prevent ovulation in the female; intrauterine devices, such as the coil, which prevent the fertilized ovum from implanting in the uterus; and male or female sterilization.

Definition of *contraceptive* (as noun):

> A device or drug serving to prevent pregnancy.

Going by these two definitions, it appears that the two words have similar meanings. The definition of *contraception* is more detailed than the definition of *contraceptive* (and approaching an encyclopedia entry). More important, it seems like *contraception* refers to the act whereas *contraceptive* refers to the physical manifestation of the act.

Is this assessment correct?

(Oxford Dictionaries Online: [contraception](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/contraception), [contraceptive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/contraceptive))

Comment: I'm guessing that the etymology of the suffixes might play a role in the distinction of meanings; this might be a good place to start.

Comment: What makes you think your assessment would not be accurate. It's there exactly as you describe it. Have you noticed people using it differently?

Comment: @Helmar -- Yes, I have noticed some using the words differently. For example, an example sentence that ODO provides below the definition of _contraception_ is, "_It had been her first time, they didn't use any contraception._" In this example sentence, _contraception_ is used to refer to a physical method, not the act itself. This is indicated by the determiner that precedes the noun ("_any_").

Comment: @Kyle *any* doesn't have to precede something physical. In this case it seems to be more *any of the methods that are available*, rather than any specific device. So I guess I would put the general concept in the upper category.

Comment: @Helmar -- You're right about "_any_." Upon some more thought, I have realized that it's not "_any_" that throws me off in the ODO example sentence, but the verb, "_use_". How does one "_use any_" practice? To reference WS2's below answer, how does one "_use any_" trumpeting? This is unintelligible. One uses any _method_ of trumpeting; one uses any _trumpet_.

Comment: @Helmar -- In your comment, you wrote, "_Contraception however is a whole bunch of methods, devices et cetera._" But according to the ODO definition I provided above, your sentence is not true. _Contraception_, according to the ODO, is the **act** (or practice) of preventing pregnancy, which includes several methods. _Contraception_ is **not** the "plural" form of contraceptive.

Comment: _Contraception_ is **not** a catchall term for contraceptives, in the way that, for example, _misconduct_ is a catchall term for various sins and blunders. _Contraception_ is an act like _plagiarism_ is an act. "_They didn't use any contraception_," makes about as much sense as, "_They didn't use any plagiarism._" An act cannot be used; only a method or object can be used. To use _contraception_ in this manner, as ODO did in its own example, reflects a different usage of _contraception_.

Comment: For example, the noun, _arrangement_ (to stick with WS2's music theme) has two discrete definitions: 1) the act of arranging music, and 2) the physical musical composition itself. It seems that some use _contraception_ similarly, i.e., as if _contraception_ has two discrete definitions, when apparently it does not. @Helmar -- It has received several downvotes now, but I hope it's becoming clear why I may have asked this question.

Answer (score 2):

*Trumpeting* is a practice. It involves playing a *trumpet*

***Contraception*** is a practice. It involves the use of a ***contraceptive***.

Answer (score 1):

[Contraception](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contraception), noun:

> Intentional prevention of ovulation, fertilization of an egg cell, or implantation of a fertilized egg in the uterine wall through the use of various drugs, devices, sexual practices, or surgical procedures. - AHDEL

[Contraceptive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contraceptive), noun

> A contraceptive drug or device, such as a birth control pill or a condom. - AHDEL

In other words, contraception is *an act* which is done with the intention of preventing pregnancy. There are *lots* of ways to do so at various points in the process of conception, including preventing ovulation (e.g. Oral Contraceptives), abstinence (a sexual practice), etc., so a few are mentioned in the definition as examples.

A contraceptive is a *device* (I would include a drug here technically as a device) used to prevent pregnancy. Because the definition is more limited, there are fewer of these than there are acts (unless you want to list every brand of every device). So there's no need to delineate the options.

> ...the physical manifestation of the act.

Not exactly. The physical manifestation of abstinence is to avoid sexual intercourse. The physical manifestation of a surgical procedure  as a means of contraception could be the tying off of the fallopian tubes or undergoing of a vasectomy.

The key difference is the word *device*. If you interpret [*device*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/device) as

> A contrivance or invention serving a particular purpose...

then it's something concrete, physical, with mass and composition, e.g. a copper IUD. However, if you define *devices* as "physical manifestations" (which is possible), then you're correct.

You can't call many of the acts of contraception *devices*.

Comment: I don't understand the  downvotes. +1 for me.